# Function Sumif in Excel

Tags: excel

I've got a problem with function **SUMIF** in Excel.

I want to use this function to calculate the total **Q** of codes that contain "**a**" and "**b**" (ex: **ababba**, **abcab**, **bac**) [as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0OZr.png).

The code I used is `SUMIF(K6:K9;"*a*b*";L6:L9)+SUMIF(K6:K9;"*b*a*";L6:L9)`. However, codes like **ababba**, **abcab** are calculated twice.

Can you help me with this? Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(L6:L9;K6:K9;"*a*";K6:K9;"*b*")
```

This will only calculate those that have both.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I know that. But can i do my work using Sumif function?

Comment: Why?  This is what SUMIFS is Specifically designed to do.  The answer is no,  By adding two SUMIF together you are using an OR statement and that will always double count.  You want an AND Statement.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Craner. I just wanna to check if the function **Sumif** could do that. :))